# Why does the value keep changing muliple times?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a simple chronometer/ stopwatch in c++. Here is the source code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    //int hours,minutes,seconds=0;
    int currHours=0,currMinutes=0,currSeconds=0;
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    while(true){
    currSeconds = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout<<currHours<<":"<<currMinutes<<":"<<currSeconds<<endl;
        if(currSeconds==60){ //Make currSeconds to 10 to avoid waiting
            currSeconds=0;
            currMinutes++;
        }
        if(currMinutes==60){
            currMinutes=0;
            currHours++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However instead of incrementing `currMinutes` by 1 and changing `currSeconds` to `0`, the `currMinutes` get incremented by `36`. I think this is because of the while loop . How should I fix this.

The part of the output where it changes  is:

```
0:0:9
0:0:9
0:0:9
0:0:9
0:0:10
0:1:10
0:2:10
0:3:10
0:4:10
0:5:10
0:6:10
0:7:10
0:8:10
0:9:10
0:10:10
0:11:10
0:12:10
0:13:10
0:14:10
0:15:10
```

Comment: looping again and again is very expensive. Why don't just use a timer?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc which library could i use?

Comment: It is C, not C++. In C++ you have great `std::chrono`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc moreover i think even a timer library would use a loop

Comment: `currSeconds=0;` this does nothing as it gets rewritten over on the next while iteration.  Imagine that line is deleted (it may as well be) do you now understand what is going wromg?

Comment: @Vedantkarandikar no, what makes you think like that? Using a loop for timer is the stupidest thing an OS writer would do, as it'll cost 100% the CPU they run, leaving nothing for the app, let alone it'll not be precise. They'll use the timer provided by the OS or library (which eventually will also have to call the OS service, which in the lowest level uses the hardware timer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop runs a lot faster than once per second.  That means you will evaluate

```
currSeconds = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

multiple times per second and since you are using second resolution your if statement will be true each time.

You either need to use a higher resolution, check if you already printed that second, or add some wait time to the loop so it doesn't run multiple times per second.

Answer (score 1):

If you unroll your while loop you realize that it goeas something like this

```
set currSeconds to time since start 
check currSeconds
set curr seconds to 0 
set currSeconds to time since start 
check currSeconds
set curr seconds to 0 
set currSeconds to time since start 
check currSeconds
set curr seconds to 0
```

you might realize that currSeconds will be the time since start in seconds everytime you check it. This is why currSeconds does not seem to be reset.
Also your programm runns faster than once per second so currSeconds will be checked in your case 36 times while it is 60.

One solution would be to make another variable that stores the number of seconds since the last minute has passed. reset this counter everytime you update the minutes and create another one for minutes to hours.

Answer (score 1):

Someting like this can help solve your problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    using namespace std;

    int currHours=0,currMinutes=0,currSeconds=0;
    long long seconds = 0;
    clock_t startTime = clock();

    while(true){
        seconds = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        currSeconds = seconds % 60;
        currMinutes = seconds / 60 % 60;
        currHours = seconds / 3600 % 24;
        std::cout<<currHours<<":"<<currMinutes<<":"<<currSeconds<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of check the seconds or minutes reach 60 get a variable in this case `seconds` with the seconds past since start and calculate from this the hours, and minutes